# Django tables2: Skipping object from queryset possible?

Tags: django, django-tables2

A database table contains a column "body" of type "text". This column contains valid JSON data. Displaying data from this table using django-tables2 should skip objects depending on JSON elements in this text field.

This filter is obviously not possible using the usual Django QuerySet mechanisms. Therefore, I want to skip an object before rendering it into the table. Something like
"before_render_row()" with the possibility to e.g. "return None" to skip the object.

Is there any possibility to do that? Thanks!

EDIT:

Table (DDL from SQlite, at Postgres "body" is type "jsonb"):

```
create table portal_d2c_messages
(
    slug              varchar(50) not null
        unique,
    record_created_dt datetime    not null,
    record_updated_dt datetime    not null,
    message_id        char(32)    not null
        primary key,
    device_mac        varchar(12) not null,
    sent_dt           datetime    not null,
    received_dt       datetime    not null,
    message_type      varchar(16) not null,
    c2d_queue_name    varchar(16) not null,
    body              text        not null,
    check ((JSON_VALID("body") OR "body" IS NULL))
);
```

View:

```
# Filter table based on JSON elements in "body".
qs = qs.filter(
    Q(body__icontains="TD1*") | Q(body__icontains="basket_id"),
    message_type__in=[
        dev_prot.D2CListMsg.MSG_TYPE_STR,
    ],
)
```

Comment: Django can, especially for postgresql databases, make advanced JSON filtering. But actually one of the main reasons that filtering is not easy is the main reason for the existence of first nromal form where putting JSON content into any sort of column is a violation of first nromal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Full ack! Unfortunately, the database is like it is. :-( That's why i hope that there's a possibility to skip objects while rendering.

Comment: can you share the current table and view?

Comment: I've added the DDL and a view snippet to my original post. But I think, this doesn't help so much.